# What is a best way to test CORS issue on multiple browser?

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-security

I am enabling CORS with Spring security in My project but after implementing what is best way test it ? Because for IE 9+ versions i am not able test it properly so couldn't get confirmation my code is working or not. I developed one Javascript client and hitting ajax request but still it is not working as expected and without proper testing not able to figure out there is issue with Spring Security or test method. I also try https://www.test-cors.org/ but not working for me.

Anyone know this please share.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I go the answer the best way to test CORS implementation is hitting API with separate JavaScript client which may be not in your project. That is the best way to test it. However modern browsers like Chrome and Firefox by default block the CORS requests so proper error will print on the browser's console. Browser's like IE will not block such request by default so make sure your server should enabled CORS requests.

I used below JavaScript code for testing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Hello CORS</title>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script>
        $.ajax({

            url: "
Your URL"   


        }).then(function(data, status, jqxhr) {

        });
    </script>
        </head>

        <body>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Make sure about Jquery versions you are using which may give problem while testing in IE.
Use latest Jquery version.